# The -s argument for the read command messes up the output

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

So my user adding script again, I noticed that, if I have the -s argument for the read command (when getting the password), the output gets messed up.

This is the code again:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Only works if you're root

for ((a=1;a>0;a)); do
 if [[ "$UID" -eq 0 ]]; then
  echo "Quit this shit anytime by pressing CTRL + C"
  read -p 'Enter one usernames: ' USERNAME
  nrchar=$(echo ${#USERNAME})
#  echo $nrchar
  spcount=$(echo ${USERNAME} | tr -cd ' ' | wc -c)
#  echo $spcount
  if [[ "${nrchar}" -gt 8 ]]; then
    echo "You may not have more than 8 characters in the username"
   elif [[ "${spcount}" -gt 0 ]]; then
    echo "The username may NOT contain any spaces"
   else
     read -p 'Enter one names of user: ' COMMENT
     read -p 'Enter one passwords of user: ' PASSWORD
     useradd -c "${COMMENT}" -m ${USERNAME}
#     echo "${?}"
     if [[ "${?}" -ne 0 ]]
     then
       echo "Username could not be created"
     else
      echo ${PASSWORD} | passwd --stdin ${USERNAME}
      passwd -e ${USERNAME}
     fi
   fi
 echo "------------------------------------------------------"
 else
  echo "You're not root, so GTFO!"
  a=0
 fi
done
```

So while this is here:

```
     read -p 'Enter one passwords of user: ' PASSWORD
```

It outputs this:

```
[vagrant@localhost vagrant]$ sudo ./exercise2-stuffs.sh
Quit this shit anytime by pressing CTRL + C
Enter one usernames: user88
Enter one names of user: user
Enter one passwords of user: 88
Changing password for user user88.
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
Expiring password for user user88.
passwd: Success
------------------------------------------------------
Quit this shit anytime by pressing CTRL + C
Enter one usernames:
```

Which is good, but if I have the -s argument:

```
     read -s -p 'Enter one passwords of user: ' PASSWORD
```

The output looks like this:

```
[vagrant@localhost vagrant]$ sudo ./exercise2-stuffs.sh
Quit this shit anytime by pressing CTRL + C
Enter one usernames: user00
Enter one names of user: user
Enter one passwords of user: Changing password for user user00.
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
Expiring password for user user00.
passwd: Success
------------------------------------------------------
Quit this shit anytime by pressing CTRL + C
Enter one usernames:
```

So my problem is here:

```
Enter one passwords of user: Changing password for user user00.
```

I know it's something really minor, but still, would be nice to know why this happens, and if it's avoidable, how would I go about avoiding it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is rock solid, but try

```
read -s -p 'Enter one passwords of user: ' PASSWORD; echo
```